# How to use 0x08

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textarea, ascii

How do you use the ASCII value of backspace `0x08` programmatically in a WinForms `TextArea`? I tried in a console program:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello" + (char)0x8 + "World");
```

And it shows as I expected:

> HellWorld

Where as I tried in a WinForms `TextArea` to fill the value:

```
txt.Text += "Hello" + (char)0x8 + "World";
```

It shows like this:

[image]

What to make backspace event to trigger other than **using Keyboard's event** to make the display as I expect by using the **value of 0x8 alone not accessing with any text field events.** Through programmatically to print "HellWorld" in text field.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the previous character, instead of using `(char)8`?

Comment: Change the Encoding of the TextBox.Text I forget what the default Encoding is for a .NET String.

Comment: Suppose you could do it like that. Then what? If you'd then place the cursor before the "W" in "HellWorld", and press backspace, you'd remove the backspace and get "HelloWorld". That's not behaviour any user will be expecting.

Comment: Don't you mean `TextBox` and not `TextArea`?

Answer (score 1):

Characters and keypress are not related directly. You would have to get a Backspace keypress into the textbox in order to erase a character.

Comment: I said not using any keyboard's event and you replied as backspace keypress

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write .NET. You can't accomplish what you want using characters in a string.

Comment: Perhaps he _does_ mean characters :P

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I'm sure he means characters. I just won't work. It's not Unix.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was jokingly referring to your downvote, where you somehow magically know exactly what OP really wants - I wasn't the one downvoting your answer btw.

Comment: Now if only the OP would agree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate someone typing in the textbox, then you might do so using [SendKeys.Send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx), e.g:

```
txt.Select();
SendKeys.Send("hello");
SendKeys.Send(((char)0x8).ToString()); // send backspace using 0x08
SendKeys.Send("{BS}"); // send backspace using predefined code
SendKeys.Send("world");
```

But pre-processing the strings seems much simpler (and safer), e.g:

```
var str = "hello";
txt.Text += str.Substring(0, str.Length-1);
```

---

Note: `SendKeys.Send` sends keystrokes to the active window. So if another window gets the focus while the above code is running, then the keystrokes might end in a different window.

Comment: window is not issue where you used 0x08

Answer (score -2):

The backspace character was introduced for thin clients that send input to a server character by character, to allow end users to fix a typo that was already sent. Modern applications usually have no use for such a character, as client applications now usually just wait until the user has finished entering data before sending it to the server.

That is why the TextBox control does not have support for it, and probably why people are wondering why you need this.

Anyway, you'll need to pre-process the data yourself before setting the TextBox's Text. You could for instance use regular expressions to simulate this behavior.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question, he mentioned "no events" and " the value of 0x8 alone" which made me assume he has to deal with characters.

Comment: I mean that character manipulation will not erase characters in the textbox or move the cursor backwards.

Comment: I covered that when I mentioned that the TextBox control does not have support for it. All I can offer is a workaround.